# Which one is correct in terms of using "organising"in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I am organising conference in university ? 
Or I am busy in organising conference in university?

Comment: Doesn't sound like either is correct...

Comment: *I am organizing a conference at a university* is correct - use articles.  *I am busy organizing a conference at a university* is also correct - again, use articles (and don't say *in organizing* in this situation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I am organising A conference in THE university..." would be acceptable.
"I am busy organising..." is also acceptable as the second option.